Windows Server 2019 Print to PDF printer missing, can't re-install it - Error - Element not found
Microsoft print to PDF went missing
Operating system: Windows Server 2019
Tried re-adding print to pdf printer:
Add printer -> File -> Microsoft Print To PDF
However, I keep getting an error:
Printer driver was not installed, Element not found.
Screenshots:
https://imgur.com/a/RaG5sGK
Any suggestions?
How can I re-install the PDF printer?
Thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That would not be the way to enable such a feature, you would need to do it through "Turn Windows Features On or Off"

First, try installing Microsoft Print to PDF using the Windows Control Panel for Windows Features.

If that fails, then, from your images, Microsoft Windows built-in Print to file driver is missing. However, rather than trying to reinstall that fundamental utility itself, do a repair of Server 2019.

Open a CMD prompt as Administrator.

Run the following to find corruption in the Server 2019 image: dism /online /cleanup-image /checkhealth

Run the following for a more complete scan: dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth

If errors have been found in either of the above, then run the following to fix errors:
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Also see these hints on fixing printing errors.


N.B.:

Make a full disk image before starting repairs.
Repair may take hours.

